# Basic understanding of probability spaces and covariance in the context of a small experiment with two measurements per person

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, covariance

I would like to confirm my basic understanding of how a probability space, random variables, and **covariance** should be 'meaningfully' defined in the context of experimentally acquired data through a simple example.

Suppose I have $3$ subjects whose names are: $A$, $B$, $C$. For each subject I collect height information and weight information.

Is the following interpretation correct? If not, could someone please provide the correct interpretation?

---

1. Let the scenario be 'encoded' by two random variables $H$ and $W$ defined relative to a *common* probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$ where $\Omega=\{A,B,C\}$ and $\mathcal F=\{\{\},\{A\},\{B\},\{C\},\{A,B\},\{A,C\},\{B,C\},\{A,B,C\}\}$.
2. Presumably, from the description of this experiment, each subject has an equal probability of being 'selected'...right? If so, it seems like $P(\{A\})=P(\{B\})=P(\{C\})=\frac{1}{3}$. Further, because each subject is measured independently relative to the other subjects, I assume that $P(\{A,B\})=P(\{A,C\})=P(\{B,C\})=\frac{2}{3}$.
3. The mapping rules associated with each random variable are then just the data that are experimentally measured (e.g. $W(A)=107$, $W(B)=123$, $W(C)=114$ and $H(A)=62$, $H(B)=68$, $H(C)=65$.

It follows, then, that the $\text{cov}(H,W)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^3\left[h_i-\text{E}(H)\right]\cdot\left[w_i-\text{E}(W)\right]$, where $\text{E}(W)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot 107+\frac{1}{3}\cdot123+\frac{1}{3}\cdot 114$ and $\text{E}(H)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot 62+\frac{1}{3}\cdot 68+\frac{1}{3}\cdot 65$

---

I am unsure if the sample space is as straightforward as $\Omega=\{A,B,C\}$. I have seen other interpretations of what a sample space should look like when $n$ measurements are taken. For example, here is a quote taken from a statistics book:

> In statistical inference and decision theory, the data set $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is viewed as an outcome of the experiment whose sample is is $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$ (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97553)

Given that my description has three observations that could be interpreted as being of the form $x_1=\{h_1,w_1\},x_2=\{h_2,w_2\}, $ and $x_3=\{h_3,w_3\}$, it is unclear to me if $\Omega=\mathbb R^3$ makes more sense for my sample space than $\{A,B,C\}$.

If this is a proper interpretation, then I am not certain how covariance is calculated because I do not know how to generate jointly distributed random variables under this new interpretation (which requires, by definition, a common probability space).

Comment: In this setting the standard assumption (which must hold) is that $A,B,C$ are three IID observations of $X=(H,W)$, a bivariate random variable s.t. $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\Omega$ is an abstract set which does not really concern us at all; $A,B,C$ are independent copies (in distribution) of $X$, mapping the same $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Your objective would be to make inference on $P_{H,W}$, the joint distribution of $(H,W)$. What you calculated would be sample statistics. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Name $A=X_1,B=X_2,C=X_3$, suppose $E[X]=(E[H],E[W])$ is known, we get for example (in the following we use column vector operations)
$$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{1\leq k \leq 3}(X_k-E[X])(X_k-E[X])'$$
as a sample variance-covariance matrix estimator of $X=(H,W)$. Indeed, by identical distribution of $X_1,X_2,X_3$,
$$E\bigg[\frac{1}{3}\sum_{1\leq k \leq 3}(X_k-E[X])(X_k-E[X])'\bigg]=E[(X-E[X])(X-E[X])']=\begin{bmatrix}
V[H]&\textrm{Cov}[H,W]\\
\textrm{Cov}[H,W]&V[W]
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Snoop Thank you for the details. For my first interpretation, my $\frac{1}{3}$ arose from the fact that the random variable mappings were injective and that $P(\{A\})=P(\{B\})=P(\{C\})$, where $P(\{A\})+P(\{B\})+P(\{C\})=1$. In your provided explanation, I am having difficulty understanding the justification behind the appearance of a $\frac{1}{3}$. Where exactly does it come from?

Comment: $1/3$ comes from $1/n$ where $n$ is the length of the sample; this appears naturally in the law of large numbers; it also makes the estimator unbiased (as above). The normalization term also appears naturally in the computation of UMVUEs of parameters of many known distributions; for a reference see Shao's mathematical statistics.

Comment: @Snoop In your first comment, you say that: "$\Omega$ is an abstract set which does not really concern us at all". Intuitively, I think I understand why this would be the case...but is it at least correct to say that the three different observations $A$, $B$, and $C$ necessarily correspond to three unique $\omega_i \in \Omega$?

Comment: Not in my knowledge: the sample is $(A(\omega),B(\omega),C(\omega)),\omega \in \Omega$; random variables are just functions.

Comment: @Snoop Hmmm. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you originally meant by the phrase: "$A,B,C$ are three IID observations of $X=(H,W)$". Is $A$, *itself*, a random variable? I assumed that $A$ simply referred to the image $(h_A,w_A)$. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes, I meant that they are random variables; it is clear from the rest of my first comment: 'independent copies (in distribution) of $X$, mapping $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$'